# Why only the last value is set during copy of excel content?

Tags: java, xssf

I'm trying to copy the content of an Excel file to another one. But only the first row.

So, I wrote this code:

```
// Step 1 : Locate path and file of input excel
File inputFile = new File("path.xlsx")
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile)
XSSFWorkbook inputWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)
int inputSheetCount = inputWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets()

// Step 2 : Locate path and file of output excel
File outputFile = new File("path2.xlsx")
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)

// Step 3 : Creating workbook for output excel file
XSSFWorkbook outputWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook()

// Step 4 : Creating sheets with the same name as appearing in input file
for(int i = 0; i < inputSheetCount; i++) {
    XSSFSheet inputSheet = inputWorkbook.getSheetAt(i)
    String inputSheetName = inputWorkbook.getSheetName(i)
    XSSFSheet outputSheet = outputWorkbook.createSheet(inputSheetName)

    int numberOfColumns = inputSheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells()

    int columnIndex = 0
    while (columnIndex < numberOfColumns && inputSheet.getRow(0).getCell(columnIndex).stringCellValue != '') {
        // Step 5 : Creating new Row, Cell and Input value in the newly created sheet
        outputSheet.createRow(0).createCell(columnIndex).setCellValue(inputSheet.getRow(0).getCell(columnIndex).stringCellValue)
        columnIndex++
    }
}

// Step 6 : Write all the sheets in the new Workbook using FileOutStream Object
outputWorkbook.write(fos)
// Step 7 : At the end of the Program close the FileOutputStream object
fos.close()
```

However, I faced to a strange problem. When I check the output file, only the last value is set, not others...

**Input file**

```
     A  |  B   |    C
1 | Key  Value   Comment 
2 | 
3 |
```

**Output file** *expected result*

```
     A  |  B   |    C
1 | Key  Value   Comment 
2 | 
3 |
```

**Output file** *actual result*

```
     A  |  B   |    C
1 |              Comment 
2 | 
3 |
```

Someone has any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `outputSheet.createRow(0)` in the while loop is the issue. It deletes the row and creates a new one every iteration and thus deleting already created cells in that row

Answer (score 0):

The `while` goes in loop. I suggest to put another `for` something like this:

```
    for(int j=0;j<numberOfColumns ;j++){
    if(inputSheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).stringCellValue != ''){
            // Step 5 : Creating new Row, Cell and Input value in the newly created sheet
            outputSheet.createRow(0).createCell(j).setCellValue(inputSheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).stringCellValue)

        }
}
```